# Error converting data type varchar to numeric CAST not working

Tags: sql-server-2005

I know this has been beaten like a dead horse. However no matter how I slice it, cast it or convert it I have the same issue.
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

```
SELECT  property_id, property_case_number, property_address, property_city, 
property_state, property_zip, property_lon, property_lat 
FROM property 
WHERE (property_active = 1) 
AND 
(property_county = (SELECT property_county FROM property AS property_1 
WHERE (property_id = 9165))) 
AND 
(property_id <> 9165)
AND
property_lon IS NOT Null 
AND 
property_lat IS NOT Null 
AND 
dbo.LatLonRadiusDistance(
CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,12),(select property_lat from property where property_id = 9165)), 
CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,12),(select property_lon from property where property_id = 9165)), 
property_lat,property_lon) <= '5'
```

I run into this issue as soon as I add dbo.LatLonRadiusDistance at the end.

dbo.LatLonRadiusDistance compares lat & lon distance in miles.

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[LatLonRadiusDistance] 
(
@lat1Degrees decimal(15,12),
@lon1Degrees decimal(15,12),
@lat2Degrees decimal(15,12),
@lon2Degrees decimal(15,12)
)
RETURNS decimal(9,4)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @earthSphereRadiusKilometers as decimal(10,6)
DECLARE @kilometerConversionToMilesFactor as decimal(7,6)
SELECT @earthSphereRadiusKilometers = 6366.707019
SELECT @kilometerConversionToMilesFactor = .621371

-- convert degrees to radians
DECLARE @lat1Radians decimal(15,12)
DECLARE @lon1Radians decimal(15,12)
DECLARE @lat2Radians decimal(15,12)
DECLARE @lon2Radians decimal(15,12)
SELECT @lat1Radians = (@lat1Degrees / 180) * PI()
SELECT @lon1Radians = (@lon1Degrees / 180) * PI()
SELECT @lat2Radians = (@lat2Degrees / 180) * PI()
SELECT @lon2Radians = (@lon2Degrees / 180) * PI()

-- formula for distance from [lat1,lon1] to [lat2,lon2]
RETURN ROUND(2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((@lat1Radians - @lat2Radians) / 2) ,2)
    + COS(@lat1Radians) * COS(@lat2Radians) * POWER(SIN((@lon1Radians - @lon2Radians) / 2), 2)))
    * (@earthSphereRadiusKilometers * @kilometerConversionToMilesFactor), 4)

END
```

I'm sure it's something to do with

```
(select property_lat from property where property_id = 9165)
```

But no matter how I cast or convert it doesn't change things.

And if I run the function by itself it doesn't give an error.

Anyone have any insights?

here is a sample row

```
8462    023-125514  15886 W MOHAVE ST   GOODYEAR    AZ  85338-0000  -112.400297000000   33.429041000000
```

property_lat & property_lon are varchar(50)

Comment: does select property_lat from property where property_id = '9165' (quotes) work?

Comment: Yes it does. 

in management studio  I get back 23 rows. Along with the error.

I just verified that it does.

    (select property_lat from property where property_id = 9165)  works

Comment: Why are you saying `<= '5'` instead of `<= 5` (no quotes)? Also what are the data types of `property_lat` and `property_lon`? Can you show us a few sample rows that produce the error so we don't have to guess?

Comment: I used 5 and it gives the same issue.

My best guess now is that property_lat, property_lon in the LatLonRadiusDistance is the issue.

The varchar that the property_lat and property_lon are in not being liked by the function. However casting them to decimal doesn't help the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with the query I got it working.

```
SELECT  [property_id], [property_case_number], [property_address], [property_city], 
[property_state], [property_zip], [property_lon], 
[property_lat] 
FROM property 
WHERE ([property_active] = 1) 
AND 
([property_county] = (SELECT b.property_county FROM property b WHERE (b.property_id =     @prop_id))) 
AND 
([property_id] <> @prop_id)
AND
[property_lon] IS NOT Null 
AND 
[property_lat] IS NOT Null 

AND
dbo.LatLonRadiusDistance(
(SELECT c.property_lat FROM property c WHERE (c.property_id = @prop_id)),
(SELECT d.property_lon FROM property d WHERE (d.property_id = @prop_id)),
CAST([property_lat] as FLOAT), 
CAST([property_lon] as FLOAT)) <= 5
```

adding the [] seems to have skirted the issue I was having.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are expecting boolean short circuit to rescue the order of evaluating your WHERE clause. This is a known fallacy: boolean operator short circuit is not guaranteed in SQL. See [On SQL Server boolean operator short-circuit](http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/) for a discussion and proof that boolean short circuit can be skipped by query optimizer. Similar topic is [T-SQL functions do no imply a certain order of execution](http://rusanu.com/2011/08/10/t-sql-functions-do-no-imply-a-certain-order-of-execution/). The gist of it is that SQL is a *declarative* language, not an imperative one.

In your case probably your cast and converts will be called for properties with IDs **different from `property_id = 9165` and `property_active=1`** and may attempt to cast string values that are not numerics to a numeric, hence the exception you see. Is difficult to give a precise diagnosis since so much information is missing from your problem description (like the *exact* definition of all object involved, including all tables, indexes, column types etc).

Your best avenue is to upgrade to SQL Server 2008 and use the built in [geography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx) type which has built-in support for [`STDistance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933808):

> This is a close approximate to the geodesic distance. The deviation of
>   STDistance() on common earth models from the exact geodesic distance
>   is no more than .25%.

Comment: If I could upgrade to 2008 I would. However that's several thousand dollars for a new server and licenses.

My best guess is that property_lat and property_lon are my issue but converting or casting them to decimal are not working right.